# getting errors while trying to build signed apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After completing my android app development, I'm trying to build a signed apk for releasing purpose in play store.

While generating signed apk, I'm getting the following error messages:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
ProGuard, version 5.2.1
Reading input...
Reading program jar [/home/anuradha/Downloads/gradle-2.10/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/2.4.0/f36d2d4e3a36b3259aaf9d004d29b4cdc6c1bfb2/picasso-2.4.0.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.4.0/support-annotations-23.4.0.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/customtabs/23.2.1/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.clans/fab/1.6.4/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/recyclerview-v7/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/multidex/1.0.1/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-maps/9.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-base/9.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-tasks/9.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-basement/9.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/de.hdodenhof/circleimageview/2.1.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.paolorotolo/appintro/4.0.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-vector-drawable/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.4.0/jars/libs/internal_impl-23.4.0.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/release/jars/2/1f/main.jar] (filtered)
Reading program directory [/codes/myapp/app/build/intermediates/classes/release] (filtered)
Reading library jar [/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/android.jar]
Reading library jar [/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar]    Note: android.support.v4.media.ParceledListSliceAdapterApi21: can't find dynamically referenced class android.content.pm.ParceledListSlice
      Maybe this is program field 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.LauncherActivity$ListItem { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.content.pm.ResolveInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard$Key { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$EngineInfo { int icon; }'
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'title' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.utils.Movie { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.facebook.share.internal.VideoUploader$UploadContext { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.facebook.share.model.GameRequestContent { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.facebook.share.model.GameRequestContent$Builder { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.AppIntroBaseFragment { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.preference.PreferenceActivity$Header { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'actionIntent' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { android.app.PendingIntent actionIntent; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { android.app.PendingIntent actionIntent; }'
Note: assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.CustomDatePicker accesses a field 'month' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.text.format.Time { int month; }'
Note: assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.CustomDatePicker accesses a field 'day' dynamically
Note: assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.CustomDatePicker accesses a field 'year' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.utils.Movie { int year; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.text.format.Time { int year; }'
Note: assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.CustomDatePicker accesses a declared field 'mSelectionDivider' dynamically
Note: assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.CustomTimePicker accesses a field 'hour' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.text.format.Time { int hour; }'
Note: assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.CustomTimePicker accesses a field 'minute' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.text.format.Time { int minute; }'
Note: assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.CustomTimePicker accesses a field 'amPm' dynamically
Note: assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.CustomTimePicker accesses a declared field 'mSelectionDivider' dynamically
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaoa accesses a declared field 'theUnsafe' dynamically
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsj accesses a declared field 'MODULE_ID' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { java.lang.String MODULE_ID; }'
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsj accesses a declared field 'MODULE_VERSION' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { int MODULE_VERSION; }'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView { void setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout { void setOnLayoutChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnLayoutChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnLayoutChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout { void setOnAttachStateChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnAttachStateChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnAttachStateChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setOnAdapterChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout { void setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView { void setOnScrollChangeListener(android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView$OnScrollChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView$OnScrollChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout { void setPanelSlideListener(android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$PanelSlideListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$PanelSlideListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout { void setOnRefreshListener(android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView { void setItemInvoker(android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder$ItemInvoker); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder$ItemInvoker'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView { void setPopupCallback(android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView$PopupCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView$PopupCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer { void setTabContainer(android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout { void setActionBarVisibilityCallback(android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$ActionBarVisibilityCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$ActionBarVisibilityCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView { void setPresenter(android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView { void setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$OnMenuItemClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$OnMenuItemClickListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView { void setActivityChooserModel(android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserModel); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserModel'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView { void setProvider(android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout { void setAttachListener(android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout { void setOnFitSystemWindowsListener(android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout { void setOnFitSystemWindowsListener(android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setRecyclerListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setRecycledViewPool(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecycledViewPool); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecycledViewPool'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setViewCacheExtension(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewCacheExtension); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewCacheExtension'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setChildDrawingOrderCallback(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ChildDrawingOrderCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ChildDrawingOrderCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$OnScrollListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$OnScrollListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setItemAnimator(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnCloseListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnCloseListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnCloseListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnSuggestionListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnSuggestionListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnSuggestionListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setSuggestionsAdapter(android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete { void setSearchView(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar { void setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$OnMenuItemClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$OnMenuItemClickListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat { void setOnInflateListener(android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat$OnInflateListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat$OnInflateListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.SlidingTabLayout { void setCustomTabColorizer(assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.SlidingTabLayout$TabColorizer); }', but not the descriptor class 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.SlidingTabLayout$TabColorizer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'assetviewer.myapp.com.finder.datepicker.SlidingTabLayout { void setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase { void setFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setDefaultAudience(com.facebook.login.DefaultAudience); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.DefaultAudience'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setLoginBehavior(com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setToolTipStyle(com.facebook.login.widget.ToolTipPopup$Style); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.ToolTipPopup$Style'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setToolTipMode(com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$ToolTipMode); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$ToolTipMode'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setProperties(com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setLoginManager(com.facebook.login.LoginManager); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.LoginManager'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView { void setOnErrorListener(com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView$OnErrorListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView$OnErrorListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView { void setCaretPosition(com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView$LikeBoxCountViewCaretPosition); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView$LikeBoxCountViewCaretPosition'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setLikeViewStyle(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$Style); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$Style'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setAuxiliaryViewPosition(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$AuxiliaryViewPosition); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$AuxiliaryViewPosition'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setHorizontalAlignment(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$HorizontalAlignment); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$HorizontalAlignment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setOnErrorListener(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$OnErrorListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$OnErrorListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu { void setLabelEllipsize(com.github.clans.fab.Label); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.github.clans.fab.Label'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu { void setOnMenuToggleListener(com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu$OnMenuToggleListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu$OnMenuToggleListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.AppIntroViewPager { void setOnNextPageRequestedListener(com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.AppIntroViewPager$OnNextPageRequestedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.AppIntroViewPager$OnNextPageRequestedListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl { void init(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton { void setOnPlusOneClickListener(com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton$OnPlusOneClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton$OnPlusOneClickListener'
Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 10 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 1 classes trying to access enclosing classes using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the inner classes attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 60 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 15 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 14 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
Warning:there were 31 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.513 secs
Information:1 error
Information:24 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

My app is running successfully while testing on devices.
How can I solve this issue? What is the proper way to prepare android app for releasing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: reformatted the ques

Comment: compile with: ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace
to see the complete error stack

Comment: And add your proguard file